# linked question considering deleted answers

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-answers, linked-questions

**linked questions** list, at right side of post is not getting updated when an answers is deleted. [See Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23194510/empty-array-does-not-equal-itself-in-javascript/23194600#23194600)

> [image: linked]

It should be excluded as deleted answers is only visible to 10k users so it might be confusing.